# How to find the determinant of this $3 \times 3$ Hankel matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, hankel-matrices

Today, at my linear algebra exam, there was this question that I couldn't solve.

---

> Prove that
> $$\det \begin{bmatrix} 
> n^{2} & (n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2} \\ 
> (n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2}  & (n+3)^{2}\\ 
> (n+2)^{2} & (n+3)^{2} & (n+4)^{2}
> \end{bmatrix} = -8$$

---

Clearly, calculating the determinant, with the matrix as it is, wasn't the right way. The calculations went on and on. But I couldn't think of any other way to solve it.

Is there any way to simplify $A$, so as to calculate the determinant?

Comment: Have you tried to utilize the determinant's variability to certain line/column actions?

Comment: Won't I have to expand the $^{2}$ in order to do that?

Comment: Am I allowed to assign a number to n?

Comment: You're not allowed to do that, no, unless you've proven that it's constant. And regarding your earlier question, find a way to use the power of $2$.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Recall that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$. Subtracting $\operatorname{Row}_1$ from $\operatorname{Row}_2$ and from $\operatorname{Row}_3$ gives 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n^2 & (n+1)^2 & (n+2)^2 \\
2n+1 & 2n+3 & 2n+5 \\
4n+4 & 4n+8 & 4n+12
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then subtracting $2\cdot\operatorname{Row}_2$ from $\operatorname{Row}_3$ gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n^2 & (n+1)^2 & (n+2)^2 \\
2n+1 & 2n+3 & 2n+5 \\
2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, subtracting $\operatorname{Col}_1$ from $\operatorname{Col}_2$ and $\operatorname{Col}_3$ gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n^2 & 2n+1 & 4n+4 \\
2n+1 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Finally, subtracting $2\cdot\operatorname{Col}_2$ from $\operatorname{Col}_3$ gives 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n^2 & 2n+1 & 2 \\
2n+1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Expanding the determinant about $\operatorname{Row}_3$ gives
$$
\det A
=
2\cdot\det
\begin{bmatrix}
2n+1 & 2\\
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=2\cdot(-4)=-8
$$
as advertised.

Answer (score 64):

Here is a proof that is decidedly not from the book. The determinant is obviously a polynomial in n of degree at most 6. Therefore, to prove it is constant, you need only plug in 7 values. In fact, -4, -3, ..., 0 are easy to calculate, so you only have to drudge through 1 and 2 to do it this way !

Comment: The book or THE book?

Comment: This is an excellent gimmick, worth remembering when you have some combinatorial identity to prove.

Comment: Very nice idea!

Comment: I might be overlooking something obvious here, but is there a "nice" way to extend this idea to "check" if $\det(A) = -8$?  (i.e. not just to prove this is constant, but also to prove the value holds?)

Comment: @anorton -8 is the value you get when you plug in one of the numbers

Comment: @hunter ah! I should have seen that.  :) thanks.

Answer (score 10):

That's not the nicest way to do it but it's quite simple and works.

To avoid developping the squares, I used $a^2-b^2 =(a+b)(a-b)$ (and $a-b$ was always $1$ when I used it). Then, once I had enough $0$s, I simply exapended by the last column.

$$\begin{array}{l}
\begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & (n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2} \\ 
(n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2}  & (n+3)^{2}\\ 
(n+2)^{2} & (n+3)^{2} & (n+4)^{2}
\end{vmatrix}
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & (n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2}-(n+1)^{2} \\ 
(n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2}  & (n+3)^{2}-(n+2)^{2}\\ 
(n+2)^{2} & (n+3)^{2} & (n+4)^{2}-(n+3)^{2}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & (n+1)^{2} &2n+3 \\ 
(n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2}  & 2n+5\\ 
(n+2)^{2} & (n+3)^{2} & 2n+7
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & (n+1)^{2}-n^{2} &2n+3 \\ 
(n+1)^{2} &(n+2)^{2}-(n+1)^{2}  & 2n+5\\ 
(n+2)^{2} & (n+3)^{2}-(n+2)^{2} & 2n+7
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2n+3 \\ 
(n+1)^{2} &2n+3  & 2n+5\\ 
(n+2)^{2} & 2n+5 & 2n+7
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2n+3 \\ 
(n+1)^{2} &2n+3  & 2n+5\\ 
(n+2)^{2}-(n+1)^{2} & 2n+5-(2n+3) & 2n+7-(2n+5)
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2n+3 \\ 
(n+1)^{2} &2n+3  & 2n+5\\ 
2n+3 & 2 & 2
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2n+3 \\ 
(n+1)^{2}-n^{2} &2n+3-(2n+1)  & 2n+5-(2n+3)\\ 
2n+3 & 2 & 2
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2n+3 \\ 
2n+1 &2  & 2\\ 
2n+3 & 2 & 2
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2n+3-(2n+1) \\ 
2n+1 &2  & 2-2\\ 
2n+3 & 2 & 2-2
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2 \\ 
2n+1 &2  & 0\\ 
2n+3 & 2 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2 \\ 
2n+1 &2  & 0\\ 
2n+3-(2n+1) & 2-2 & 0-0
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
n^{2} & 2n+1 &2 \\ 
2n+1 &2  & 0\\ 
2 & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= 2\begin{vmatrix} 
2n+1 &2\\ 
2 & 0
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= -8
\end{array}$$

Comment: how come your first equation holds?

Comment: column 3 <- column 3 - column 2

Comment: Thanks , i can't believe i didn't see that.

Comment: I don't know if this would fit in the box allocated to the question on the exam :p

Comment: Think outside the box.